# Show or hide div for a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got two divs. The second one has to be shown or hide depending on a specific value for the first two. First of all I can't retrieve the value selected on the first div (a dropdownlist value). And then I can't do the comparison between two values.

I've got this:

```
function getQuestionOptionValues(element) {
        var ret = new Array();
        x$(element).find("input").filter(function() {return this.checked;}).each(function(optelement, index, xui) {
        ret.push(parseInt(x$(optelement).attr("name").toString().replace(/Q\d+_QO/g, "")));
        });
        return ret;
    }
```

This is the function to retrieve the value on the first div.

ret goes to a variable like this:

```
var vcond = [3583];
var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ1113");
```

And the I've got to do the comparison between ret and cond to show or hide the second div.

```
x$("div#divQ550").show();
```

My divs are like this:

```
<div class="section row" id="divQ1113" style="display: block;">

<div class="section row principal_question">
    <label>Cual fue su motivo de estancia</label>   </div>

    <div class="section row sub_question">
        </div>

<div class="section row">
    <select name="Q1113" id="Q1113">
        <option value="">Opciones</option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3417"> </option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3582">Turismo</option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3583">Negocios</option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3584">Familia</option>
</select>   </div>
</div>

<div id="Q550"><label style="text-align: center;">0</label><input value="0"  style="display: block; margin: 9px 0px 0px -2px;" type="radio" name="Q550" id="Q550"></div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all your question is confusing , see I made jsfiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/1oapfq2k/ Explain what you want ?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is I.E. If I select "Turismo" on the first div I have to hide the div with the radio button. If i select another option, like "Negocios", the div with the radio button must be shown.

Comment: On what parameter you applied check whether to show a div or not ? On id ? if yes then how ?

Comment: I'm so sorry I have copy/paste the wrong code. function getQuestionOptionValues(element) {

            var ret = "";
            ret = x$(element).$(":selected").text();
            return ret;
        }

Comment: x$ is equivalent to $(document).ready(function()

Comment: This works for me but I want to do the same in a separate function: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Q1113").on('click',function() {
       $("#Q550").hide()
       alert($(":selected").text());
    });
});

Comment: then do it in separate function , what is the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure but when I put this on a separete function alert shows me nothing.